# backbone.js - When i change the name attribute nothing is updated and changed function not triggers

Tags: backbone.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backbone.js - change not triggering while the name change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453219/backbone-js-change-not-triggering-while-the-name-change)

I made a function to learn backbone... for that i made a 'json' locally and calling that in my fetch function. as well i keep calling the fetch function every 10sec. apart from that, in between i am updating my 'local json' by manually, after the change the `fetch` should get me the updated stuff but it not getting me.

As well i added a function to trigger, while the name `attribute` change but as well not triggering when the josn update the name

this both are confusing me as well i din't get a good tutorial to learn this... any one help me to sort out this or suggest me the correct way to achieve both?

code :

```
(function($){

var list = {};

list.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    name:'need the name'
  }
});

list.collect = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:list.model,
  url : 'data/names.json',
  initialize:function(){
    this.fetch();
    this.keepUpdate();
  },
  keepUpdate:function(){
    var that = this;
    var updateData = function(){
      that.fetch();
      myTimeout = setTimeout(updateData,10000);
    }
    var myTimeout = setTimeout(updateData,10000);
  }
});


list.view = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize:function(){
    this.collection = new list.collect();
    this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
    this.collection.on('change:name',function(){ console.log('name changed')}); // not triggers while i change the name attrb..
  },
  render:function(){
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(data){
      console.log(data.get('name')); // no update getting here..
    })
  }
});

var newView = new list.view();    

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453219/backbone-js-change-not-triggering-while-the-name-change ?