# Backbone.js - add parameter sending to fetch not trigger the collection

Tags: backbone.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backbone.js - change not triggering while the name change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453219/backbone-js-change-not-triggering-while-the-name-change)
>   [Backbone - how get this sort out… some part still not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457874/backbone-how-get-this-sort-out-some-part-still-not-clear)

in my backbone function, i am keep fetching the data using `setTimout` while i fetch the data, i am sending property as `{add:true}` so it means, the model which i am getting newly will going to add with existing collection, when the collection get the model added , it should trigger the `add` method.

But i am not getting the trigger on the after add process made in my collection. but i am fetching the data in view process, it is not correct.

my collection:

```
list.collect = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:list.model,
  url : 'data/names.json',
  initialize:function(){
     this.fetch({success:this.prompter});
     this.on("add", this.addOne, this);//it should get triggered while added the model
  },
  addOne:function(e){
    console.log('addone'); // the method not called
  }
});
```

my view :

```
list.view = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize:function(){
    this.collection = new list.collect();

    var that = this;
    var updateData = function(){
      that.collection.fetch({add:true}); // i am passing add:true!
      myTimeout = setTimeout(updateData,10000)
    }
    var myTimeout = setTimeout(updateData,10000)

    this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);

  },
  render:function(data){
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(data){
      //console.log(data.get('name'));
    })
  }
});
```

any idea about the issue please?

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457874/backbone-how-get-this-sort-out-some-part-still-not-clear, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453219/backbone-js-change-not-triggering-while-the-name-change and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452053/backbone-js-when-i-change-the-name-attribute-nothing-is-updated-and-changed-fu